# With Appharbor is it possible to get an email when a build fails?

Tags: appharbor

Is it possible to have appharbor send an email to a developer or list of users when a build fails?

Answer (score 2):

You can set up your own service to accomplish this using [AppHarbor Service Hooks](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/3rd-party-integrations/developing-a-service-hook). Use [TweetHarbor](http://tweetharbor.apphb.com/) and having Twitter send the emails is another option. Also check out this blog post on getting [AppHarbor build notifications to Hipchat/Campfire chatrooms](http://www.laurentkempe.com/post/Using-Appharbor-service-hook-to-get-build-status-in-HipChat-rooms.aspx).

Comment: I did it for IM client (Google Talk), check here http://chandermani.blogspot.in/2012/07/appharbor-build-notification-using.html